# Sharepoint Online: Set Content Editor Web Part Content with Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, content-editor-web-part

I want to update the content shown by the CEWP using Powershell. I've been using PnP-Powershell but can't find a way to update the content/xml.

Answer (score 0):

Used PnP to export CEWP XML, remove web part, then re-create web part.